# JSP running on custom class

Tags: jsp

I would like to inherit from the class a standard JSP page uses (HttpServlet), so I can add some methods and properties for use in the jsp pages.

Then use the extends attribute in a page tag to use my custom class and still show the normal html, etc from the jsp page.

I thought this would be simple but after days of Googling and viewing Stack Overflow posts nothing works.

I'm not sure what is wrong, if I just have an empty class it causes an error as there is no implementation of doGet (But that is weird since there must be an implementation of doGet in the HttpServlet class which I am inheriting).

If I do implement a doGet method the normal jsp page does not show. Is there a method I can call in my doGet method that would send the jsp contents in the response?

I think I'm just not understanding something basic. Please can someone help me as I'm now lost.

Comment: try to put your code here so we can reach the problem where !!

Comment: I didn't find a way to use oop nicely with jsp. I think MVC is the way to go.